# Unable to find Submit button in gerrit any scenario

Tags: git, gerrit

I have stucked with one issues from last last 12 hours and not able to find a solution in gerrit.

I have installed test Gerrit instance "2.14.3". from last few hours, I am trying to find a submit button and failed badly. Tried many options and many reference in google but could not get Submit button Enabled.

Note, I am pushing the change via one registered user and  trying to submit via admin user but "SUBMIT" button is not being displayed at all.

Few Quick Commands to check the senario

```
git clone http://13.126.209.78:8080/test1
curl -Lo .git/hooks/commit-msg http://13.126.209.78:8080/tools/hooks/commit-msg
touch file1.txt;git add .;git commit -m"adding first"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

and Found No Submit button.
Any clue, where I am doing mistakes?

Here is the details of project.config

```
[project]
    description = Access inherited by all other projects.
[receive]
    requireContributorAgreement = false
    requireSignedOffBy = false
    requireChangeId = true
    enableSignedPush = false
[submit]
    mergeContent = true
[capability]
    administrateServer = group Administrators
    priority = batch group Non-Interactive Users
    streamEvents = group Non-Interactive Users
[access "refs/*"]
    read = group Administrators
    read = group Anonymous Users
[access "refs/for/*"]
    addPatchSet = group Registered Users
[access "refs/for/refs/*"]
    push = group Registered Users
    pushMerge = group Registered Users
[access "refs/heads/*"]
    create = group Administrators
    create = group Project Owners
    forgeAuthor = group Registered Users
    forgeCommitter = group Administrators
    forgeCommitter = group Project Owners
    push = group Administrators
    push = group Project Owners
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Administrators
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project Owners
    label-Code-Review = -1..+1 group Registered Users
    submit = group Administrators
    submit = group Project Owners
    editTopicName = +force group Administrators
    editTopicName = +force group Project Owners
[access "refs/meta/config"]
    exclusiveGroupPermissions = read
    read = group Administrators
    read = group Project Owners
    create = group Administrators
    create = group Project Owners
    push = group Administrators
    push = group Project Owners
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Administrators
    label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Project Owners
    submit = group Administrators
    submit = group Project Owners
[access "refs/tags/*"]
    create = group Administrators
    create = group Project Owners
    createTag = group Administrators
    createTag = group Project Owners
    createSignedTag = group Administrators
    createSignedTag = group Project Owners
[label "Code-Review"]
    function = MaxWithBlock
    defaultValue = 0
    copyMinScore = true
    copyAllScoresOnTrivialRebase = true
    value = -2 This shall not be merged
    value = -1 I would prefer this is not merged as is
    value = 0 No score
    value = +1 Looks good to me, but someone else must approve
    value = +2 Looks good to me, approved
[label "Verified"]
    function = MaxWithBlock
    value = -1 Fails
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Verified
    copyAllScoresIfNoCodeChange = true
```

Here is the details of gerrit.config

```
gerrit]
        basePath = git
        serverId = 99472c41-5ed3-411e-a42f-36fdd890ff96
        canonicalWebUrl = http://ip-172-31-2-138.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8080/
[database]
        type = h2
        database = /opt/review_site/db/ReviewDB
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = DEVELOPMENT_BECOME_ANY_ACCOUNT
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
[container]
        user = root
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el7_4.x86_64/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8080/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

[image: No Submit button]

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue, everything is working as designed. The "Submit" button only is showed when the change is "Approved". In your case, you need to have "Code-Review +2" AND "Verified +1". You just have the first one. Click on the "Reply" button and add a "Verified +1" vote then the "Submit" button will show up.

Note: it's possible that you don't have permission to add a "Verified +1" vote, in this case you'll need to add permission to this first.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [gerrit issue 6959](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=6959):

> The "`Submit`" button should show, maybe in grey if the CL is not Verified+1
>
> What do you see instead?
>
> No "`Submit`" button.
> **Took me some ask-around to figure out I needed to click "`Verified+1`"**

[image: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Gerrit/img/xwebreview50.png.pagespeed.ic.8-R3k9h-LU.png]

Comment: Hi Von, Thanks for your comments. I was expecting the same behavior as you mentioned. But even i m surprised with view without Submit button. I did not leave even any url left which is found in google but issues is persisit. In order to reproduce the issues, you may setup one sample gerrit with most latest version and use my gerrit.config and project.config. that would be good

Comment: @scmGalaxy Yes, that is why I mentioned the issue: there is no button unless you click on Verified first, bring the Verified counter to +1.

Comment: i just updated the images in questions. Probably you will get my prb now